# Validar fechas con isDate no me funciona aunque tenga instalado moment

Tags: angular, momentjs

Aquí: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/shared/inline-edit/inline-edit.component.ts

En el menú Avales>ver-editar al pinchar en cualquier celda "Fecha Aval"

[image: celda]

Estoy intentando editar un campo de tipo fecha, y antes de pasar el valor al servicio REST que hace el put en la base de datos, quiero validar que lo introducido es de tipo fecha. Para ello, uso esto:

ListadoAvales.component.html

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaAval">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Fª Aval</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [satPopoverAnchor]="p" (click)="p.open()">
      {{element.fecha | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
      <sat-popover #p [hasBackdrop]="true" xAlign="start" yAlign="start"
        (closed)="updateFechaAval(element, $event)">
      <inline-edit [value]="element.fecha| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"></inline-edit>
      </sat-popover>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

ListadoAvales.Component.ts

```
updateFechaAval(aval: any, fechaAval: Date) {
if (fechaAval == null) { return; };

if(isDate(fechaAval)){
  aval.fecha = formatDate(fechaAval, 'dd-MM-yyyy', this.locale);
  console.log('aval con los cambios', aval);
  this.dataServiceAvales.putAval(aval.id, aval)
  .subscribe(
    data => {

    }
    , err => console.error(err)
    , () => { }
  );
}
else{
  let snackBar = this.snackbar.open('La Fecha del aval debe ser de tipo fecha', '', { duration: 3000 });
}
```

}

Pero, aunque meta valores tipo "06/01/2017", siempre sale por la rama del else, y cuando depuro en consola me sale este error:

[image: error]

Es decir, compila bien, pero luego no me deja usar el método IsDate.

[image: isDate]

Y, entonces, no sé cómo hacer la validación.

¿Alguna idea, por favor?

Comment: Lo has importado el fichero donde implementas el componente?

Comment: que te muestra console.log(moment(fechaAval, 'dd-MM-yyyy,true).isValid())

Comment: En el fichero donde hago la validación he importado isDate: import { isDate } from 'moment'; y cuando intento ejecutar esto en consola: moment(fechaAval, 'dd-MM-yyyy,true).isValid() obtengo Uncaught RegerenceError: moment is not defined

Comment: entonces doy una respuesta cualquier cosa comentame saludos

Comment: He importado esto import * as moment from 'moment'; y la sentencia moment(fechaAval, 'dd-MM-yyyy',true).isValid() cuando la intento ejecutar depurando por consola me sigue diciendo que moment is not defined

Comment: elimine la repuesta te consulto cerraste el editor y lo volviste a abrir a mi a veces  debo hacer esto para que reconozca nuevas importaciones si no lo soluciona tratare de ejecutar  esa parte de tu codigo en un proyecto mio

Comment: @nestdan moment.isDate(fechaAval) tampoco me deja depurarlo con el mismo mensaje. La consola no me ofrece ningún método para moment

Comment: instalaste con npm install --save moment

Comment: probe con mi configuaracion angular 12.2.0 typescript 4.3.5 moment 2.29-1 y funciona con las instrucciones que antes te indique. En stackbliz veo que tenes al moment.d.ts bien unica diferencia significativa que encuentro en tu proyecto "typescript": "~4.0.2"

Comment: @nestdan la depuración la estoy haciendo en mi proyecto en local con angular 12 typescript 4.5.4 y moment 2.29.1 y obtengo el momento not defined

Comment: @kintela, prueba haciendo la importación así `import moment from 'moment';`. El problema es que tu variable `fechaAval` es de tipo cadena (si haces `console.log(typeof fechaAval)` lo verás). Tendrás que pasar esa cadena a fecha. Al no usar un formato tomado como estándar tendrás que hacer la transformación para que lo entienda como un formato de fecha válido

Comment: @kintela te paso link de github instale primero las librerias que usas en un proyecto luego copie el codigo no tuve tiempo de verlo bien pero le agregue un pipe para modem y en listado-avales.component unos console.log con moment tiene creo todas las libreias que usas y reconoce a moment en cuanto al servidor como me da 404 probe otras cosas entre ellas que acepte moment https://github.com/nestdanchia/-kintela/tree/main/src/app

Comment: @nestdan perdona pero no entiendo lo del Pipe para modern. Eso donde está? te refieres a esto: <inline-edit [value]="element?.fecha| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"></inline-edit>

Comment: Como te comente vi solo si reconocia a moment usando tus librerias lo probe en 
listado-avales.component.ts en su   ngOnInit(){} mostrando por consola fechas con
moment y tambien en app.component.html mediante un Pipe personalizado moment {{ date | dateFormat: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}

Comment: y lo reconoce sin problemas si luego al poder disponer de Pipes moment se puede mejorar el codigo no lo pense aun  .Como me da 404 para otras pruebas y me interesa las libreria que usaste 
voy a probar con una tabla local con datos similares a los tuyos usando sat-popover y los subo al repo .No probaste el codigo del repro?

Comment: @kintela no se si leiste mi mensaje anterior ahora en el repo probe en app.component .ts una tabla con columna de tipo Date para ver la funcionalidad de editar online agregando el pipe moment si la fecha es valida cambio el formato y lo muestra por consola es un borrador con mas tiempo lo mejoro ya que  hay eventos que no capturo  muestar en la tabla un formato de date para editar muestar otro y en el componente varia el formato esta muy buena sat-popover https://github.com/nestdanchia/-kintela/blob/main/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: o sea lo mestro en la tabla por ejemplo como  December 17, 1995  se edita  con mes dia año y finalmente se transforma a dia mes año para probar el pipe moment

Answer (score 0):

Intenta importar moment de esta forma:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Seguidamente podrás validar la fecha así:

```
if (moment.isDate(fechaAval)) {

}
```

Saludos.

Comment: en los comentarios veras que ya probo esa opcion